# How to count the number of letters in a random string?

Tags: javascript

If there is a random string get from SERVER:

```
var str='I am a student in XXX university, I am interested...'
```

The `str` can contain random number of words with spaces. That's the content of the string is unpredictable.

In javascript, how to count the number of letters in the string (**spaces** between words are **exclusive** from the counting). For example "I have a car" should be counted 9 letters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you only want alpha characters, get rid of other characters first using `replace()`:

```
var str='I am a student in XXX university, I am interested...';

alert(str.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length);
```

You can add `0-9` to the `[^A-Z]` character class if you want to count numbers as letters.  If you only want to remove white-space, change the regular expression to `/\s/g`

Comment: What about if I would like to take space into account?

Comment: @Mellon: if you want to include spaces but exclude other punctuation, change the character class to `[^ A-Z]`.

Answer (score 8):

You could coiunt the number of matches using the regex `\w` - which matches any alphanumeric character or `[a-zA-Z]` for any alpha character

eg:

```
var numChars = "I have a car".match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length;
// numChars = 9
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/GBvCp/

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `_`, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 7):

We split every space and join the array again:

```
var str='I am a student in XXX university, I am interested...'

str = str.split(" ").join("");

alert(str.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AwVBJ/

Comment: Is a `,` a letter too now? :P

Comment: @Andrew: to be fair, the OP did only explicitly mention spaces.  However, it's probably the case that he doesn't want to count the other junk either.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way:

```
var str = "I have a car";   
while (str.indexOf(' ') > 0) { 
    str = str.replace(' ' , '');
    }
var strLength = str.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp = str;

temp= temp.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g,"");
```

`temp.length` will give u the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of spaces (e.g. http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript-how/70527-count-occurrence-character-string.html), then subtract that from the length.

```
    var testString = ' my test string has  a number of spaces ';
    alert('Number of spaces:' + (testString .replace(/[^ ]/g, '').length));
    alert('Number of characters:' + (testString.length));
    alert('Number of characters excluding spaces:' + 
        (testString.length - (testString     .replace(/[^ ]/g, '').length)));
```

Note: it correctly counts double spaces and spaces at the ends.