# Accessing JSON object duplicated values in one array

Tags: json, node.js

I'm wanting to access '`value: '<p>Testing the post</p>',`' So i can count the amount of chars and respond back this back to the user. I can't seem to access this.

Variable being called

```
const links = req.renderData.templateFields
```

object returned

```
 [{ name: 'permalink_slug',
    sqlType: 'VARCHAR',
    sqlDef: '(255)',
    rowTemplate: 'rows/_hidden',
    uiFieldType: 'permalink',
    uiLabel: 'Permalink',
    options: {},
    value: 'http://localhost:3000/posts/testing',
    partial: 'fields/permalink/permalink' },
  { name: 'content',
    sqlType: 'LONGTEXT',
    sqlDef: '',
    rowTemplate: 'rows/_default-row',
    uiFieldType: 'tinymce',
    uiLabel: 'Content',
    options: {},
    value: '<p>Testing the post</p>',
    partial: 'fields/tinymce/tinymce' }]
```

I've tried

```
 for (var i = 0, l = links.length, obj; i < l; i++ )
    {
      obj = links[i];
      links[i] = new Object();
     links[i][obj.name] = obj.value;
      console.log(links[i])
    }
```

But this returns all the names plus it deletes my whole page since it turns everything into an object

Comment: As you stated, templateFields is an object, so the JSON fields will behave like properties. Have you tried just using `obj=links[i]; obj.name=obj.value; console.log(obj.name);` to get the value?

Comment: @John Doi, does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330740/1333836) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `const links = req.renderData.templateFields` is the following **array** of objects (it's actually an array, not an object like you mentioned in your question):

```
[{
    // ... bla bla
    value: 'http://localhost:3000/posts/testing',
},
{
    // ... bla bla
    value: '<p>Testing the post</p>',
}]
```

Then, this is how to enhance it with a property containing the amount (count) of chars for each `value` attribute:

```
// Simple way to count the number of letters in a random string,
// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349353/1333836 but feel free
// to use any method for calculating the count you prefer.
const countCharacters =
    (str) => str.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length;

const enhancedWithCount = links.map(link => {
    // for each link, introduce a `count` attribute;
    link.count = countCharacters(link.value);

    return link;
});

// Finally, do res.json(enhancedWithCount)
// or whatever you want with the `enhancedWithCount` array anyways.
```

Here's how `enhancedWithCount` looks finally:

```
[{
    // ... bla bla
    value: 'http://localhost:3000/posts/testing',
    count: 25
},
{
    // ... bla bla
    value: '<p>Testing the post</p>',
    count: 16
}]
```